# Script to save and rename attatchment from an email

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email

I have a software that sends an email with a CSV file attached with data from all the printers in the network once a week.
I have it installed in multiple places so I receive multiple files with the same name.

I need to schedule a script that saves the attached csv files in a folder in my ubuntu server, unfortunately I cannot configure the name of the file sent at the source and all the files need to have different names so:

- download the email in my Ubuntu server
- save and rename based on the address of the sender the attachments in a local folder (overwriting the old one)
- delete the email it just downloaded

I'm aware of `fetchmail` and `munpack` but I'm not 100% sure if it allows renaming and that's a crucial point of the whole thing.
Is this thing possible with just bash command?

Comment: Why don't you rename the file with an `mv` command after receiving it?

Comment: @xenoid the server has to do it automatically without supervision and I don't know if there's some sort of `foreach` i can use with the file retreived with `fetchmail` in case of multiple emails.